# click thumbnail img, find alt value... then addClass to all images with same alt value

Tags: jquery

I have main images and thumbnails. I want to add 'active' class to main image when the thumbnail image is clicked... the only commonality is the alt tag.

This is what I have tried.

```
$('#thumbnails img').click(function () {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    var tag = $("img").attr(alt);
    $("#mainImages").find(tag).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this to get the tag with your alt value `var tag = $("img[alt='"+alt+"']");`

```
$('#thumbnails img').click(function () {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    var tag = $("img[alt='"+alt+"']");
    $("#mainImages").find(tag).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Nice. But the "alt" attribute value cannot contain a few characters, like `]` for example. It would break the selector syntax. How would we solve this and make the solution bullet-proof?

Comment: IDK, but OP didn't mentioned anything about what alt tag value is going to be Or what it looks like _at least_.

Comment: I've done some research (http://www.google.com/search?q=escape+attribute+value+for+selector), and found the answer (see next comment)

Comment: `$('img', '#mainImages').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('alt') == alt; }).addClass('active');` - the "var tag" line becomes unnecessary

Comment: So I revised the script based on post and comment... I'll rewrite answer

Comment: currently the ALT tag is the filename... but, will be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I interpreted from post and comments..

```
$('#thumbnails img').click(function () {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('#thumbnails img', '#mainImages img').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('alt') == alt;}).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this looks right, but is still not working in my environment. I appreciate the help!